# What's the difference between time and energy?

Tags: energy, time

I'm an ongoing student of Physics. Please could anyone give me the explanations for the observed physical phenomena of: time and energy. Especially, their differences and how they relate to oneanother. Many thanks for your time and insights.

Comment: "As in the Heat Death of The Universe, when entropy reaches a level where no more energy can be released, there will be no more events and so no more time." I have seen many distinguished physicists make versions of this claim, but I think the basis of it is shaky. When entropy is maximized I would say there are no beings to experience the passage of time, but that doesn't mean that time isn't still passing. It's a tree falls in the forest kind of thing

Comment: Even in the Heat Death of The Universe there are fluctuations, thus, time :-)

Comment: You can very roughly think of them as having a similar connection to how position and momentum are related

Comment: I don't know why the 3 helpful comments above have been flagged ? Please could someone advise me how to try and get an answer to my question. Thanks

Comment: The comments above have been upvoted, not flagged. For advice about workshopping this question, you might visit [chat].

Comment: Thanks very much Rob. I've clicked on Physics Chat, but it's not clear to me what to do next to workshop my question. I don't want to mess-up again when  asking the question and be locked-out. Guidance would be much appreciated on how to do as you suggest and how to ask the question correctly. Thanks. Ken

Comment: Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5):

There is no equivalence between time and energy as they are two different things. However, the Noether current for translations in time is energy. This is then bundled in with spatial momentum to make for the spacetime 4-momentum.

Comment: "Is there equivalence between information, energy and matter ?" is a related question, which I now see has been allowed and not closed. I don't understand why my question has been closed and how I should modify it for it to be allowed or reopened. Please could someone advise me on this and what I could do next constructively to meet the site's requirements. Thank you. Sincerely, Ken.allsopp@hotmail.com